# google charts not supporting in angularjs's view...i placed inline script code in ng-view's page

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization

google charts not supporting in angularjs's view...i placed inline script code in ng-view's page????

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="slideshow" >
    <div id='slideshow1' class="slide" style='width: 900px; height: 300px;'></div>
    <div id='slideshow2' class="slide" style="display: none" style='width: 900px; height: 300px;'></div>
    <div id='slideshow3' class="slide" style="display: none" style='width: 900px; height: 300px;'></div>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function startSlides(start, end, delay) {
        setTimeout(slideshow(start,start,end, delay), delay);
    }
    function slideshow(frame, start, end, delay) {
        return (function() {
            $('#slideshow' + frame).fadeOut();
            if (frame == end) { frame = start; } else { frame += 1; }
            setTimeout(function(){$('#slideshow' + frame ).fadeIn();}, 850);
            setTimeout(slideshow(frame, start, end, delay), delay + 850);
        })
    }
    // usage: startSlides(first frame, end frame, delay time);
    startSlides(1, 3, 3000);
</script>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['hour', 'Total API Requests'],
                ['1:00', 148411 ],
                ['2:00', 388119 ],
                ['3:00', 145930 ],
                ['4:00', 138300 ],
                ['5:00', 272510 ],
                ['6:00', 429966 ],
                ['7:00', 553685 ],
                ['8:00', 633561 ],
                ['9:00', 648881 ],
            ]);
            var options = {
                title: 'Samsung eu API Statistics',
                width:1000,
                height:300
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('slideshow1'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['hour', 'Total API Requests'],
            ['1:00', 692423 ],
            ['2:00', 676998 ],
            ['3:00', 641638 ],
            ['4:00', 556973 ],
            ['5:00', 453528 ],
            ['6:00', 347283 ],
            ['7:00', 250954 ],
            ['8:00', 402833 ],
            ['9:00', 334050 ],
        ]);
        var options = {
            title: 'Samsung usa API Statistics',
            width:1000,
            height:300
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('slideshow2'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['hour', 'Total API Requests'],
            ['1:00', 441440 ],
            ['2:00', 495788 ],
            ['3:00', 528438 ],
            ['4:00', 570761 ],
            ['5:00', 628285 ],
            ['6:00', 570433 ],
            ['7:00', 557259 ],
            ['8:00', 577519 ],
            ['9:00', 612925 ],
        ]);
        var options = {
            title: 'Samsung asia API Statistics',width:1000,
            height:300

        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('slideshow3'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your DataTable:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Sample');
data.addColumn('number', 'Altitudine');
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    data.addRow(['', elevations[i].elevation]);
}
```

your first column is type `'string'`, and you are setting all values to `''`.  If you change those to type `'number'` and replace the empty strings with the distance along the path, then you will get the results you want.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'Sample');
data.addColumn('number', 'Altitudine');
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    data.addRow([i * pathLength / sampleCount, elevations[i].elevation]);
}
```

`sampleCount` is the number of samples taken (which you can take either from the path options or from the length of the `elevations` array), and `pathLength` is the total length of the path.  I don't know how to get the path length from the path, though.